# cant pass enum type properly in html

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular, enums

I want to pass an enum type in my html to a method.

```
export enum ListType {typeOne, typeTwo, typeThree}
```

now in my button click I want to do this:

```
<button md-button
          (click)="setListToDisplay(ListType.typeOne)"
          class="md-primary">Matcher
  </button
```

this is the function in the component.ts

```
public setListToDisplay(type: ListType):void {
    switch (type) {
      case ListType.matcherView:
        this.listToDisplay = this.listOneToDisplay;
      case ListType.expediteView:
        this.listToDisplay = this.listTwoToDisplay;
      case ListType.typeThree:
        this.listToDisplay = this.listThToDisplay;
    }
  }
```

this is my error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in
>   [listToDisplay in MyCmp@62:57]

but it dosent work, how should I do it properly?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Are there errors?

Comment: What is the scope of your enum? It should be used as your component property in order to be familiar in its HTML.

Comment: @NitzanTomer added my error, sorry forgot

Comment: @AranS its in the component ts right under the imports

Comment: Can you show more of the class code? For example, where are the `listOneToDisplay`, `listTwoToDisplay` are defined?

Comment: `this.listToDisplay` doesn't have a value assigned at the time when `setListToDisplay` is called. We need to see more code to diagnose the problem.

Comment: @jackmiao You have `typeOne` and `typeTwo` members in enum but in `setListToDisplay` you check for `matcherView` and `expediteView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a property **inside** the `@Component`-decorated class for you to be able to reference the enum at the template.

So if you have a template/code similar to the one below, add the property as showed:

```
import { stuff } from 'whatever';
...

export enum ListType {typeOne, typeTwo, typeThree}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
  ...
  <button md-button
          (click)="setListToDisplay(ListType.typeOne)"
          class="md-primary">Matcher
  </button>
  ...
  `
  ...
})
export class MyComponent {

  public setListToDisplay(type: ListType):void {
    switch (type) {
      case ListType.matcherView:
        this.listToDisplay = this.listOneToDisplay;
      case ListType.expediteView:
        this.listToDisplay = this.listTwoToDisplay;
      case ListType.typeThree:
        this.listToDisplay = this.listThToDisplay;
    }
  }

  // add a property with the enum name, like this:
  public ListType = ListType;    // <<<-------------------------------- add this property 

  // with the above you can now use the ListType.typeOne in the template.

}
```